forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault
While running the code I got following error (in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS):
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred

The current space usage is :
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi       2.5Gi        57Gi        17Mi       2.3Gi        59Gi
Swap:           38Gi          0B        38Gi


What version of Ubuntu is being used?

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

The above-mentioned segmentation error can be successfully  handled using
ulimit -s unlimited

as it removes the limit set on resource usage for running processes and they can take as much memory as system's physical memory.

SIGSEV, or Segmentation fault, is how Linux says "Illegal Memory Access". Check for a pooly configured forrtl, or a missing shared library (with ldd $(type -p forrtl). If you have missing libraries, you can find out which package provides them with dpkg -S <libraryname>.
